# Why are there unverified add-ons on the G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-workspace

On Google [website](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-review), it is written that to publish an add-on on the G Suite market place, the add-on must go through a review process. It means that there shouldn't be any "unverified" add-ons on the marketplace. However, I can see that there are quite a few unverified add-ons on the G Suite marketplace, such as [this](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/mail_merge_with_attachments/223404411203).

Can anyone please explain why such add-ons are there?

Comment: This is not a programming or development question. This is a customer support question for a vendor. Maybe one of the Google PMs will comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Google employee or Google PM but I am answering this based on my knowledge. When an application is developed using Google APIs the developer must create a project on the Developers console in Google Cloud Platform and enable the APIs that are going to be used by  the application. Besides the APIs enabling and the project creation there is a specific screen where you have to add some API scopes and some of them are sensitive scopes that has to pass through a verification process with Google, if the application is still unverified all users who try to access will receive this unverified app message, also when the scopes are updated the developer must request verification again.

All this process has to be completed for security purposes, to make sure that the applications are not running processes on the backend that can compromise your information as a user. You can find more information on this Help Center Article from Google Cloud Platform https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

So answering your main question directly some of these can happen.

1. Developer requested a re-verification due to updates on the API
   scopes.
2. New requirements from Google that request Developers to complete a new
   verification process for security reasons.
3. Change on policies that forces a new verification process.

I am not saying this is happening but as my understanding this could be one of the reasons, also keep in mind that Google is always updating and strengthening policies and security measurements for the end user to be safe and feel safe when using their services or services created with their APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So is it true that an add-on must be verified first before it is published on the marketplace and after that it could be asked to be re-verified for some reason (e.g. the ones you listed)?

Comment: AFAIK a re-verification can ocurr when some scopes are modified or when security policies change on Google side and required the developer to request a new verification, this is always to secure users personal informationand make sure that any change will not affect the final user.